# Searching software to return UK Postal Addresses from polygon

Tags: polygon, software-recommendations, address, united-kingdom, search

Does anyone know of software that will return a list of UK postal addresses from a polygon drawn on a map?  We are currently using AFD Postcode Plus but that only allows us to do a radial search.

A desktop or web-based solution would be fine. Ideally, it would be pay for what you use, rather than a large upfront fee.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Thanks you for taking the Tour. Unfortunately, our Focused question/Best answer model doesn't support *opinion-based* software requests. Fortunately, [softwarerecs.se] exists for software recommendtations; I suggest you try there.

Comment: If the format is compatible with arcgis and/or qgis you can do freehand polygon selections https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/general_tools.html#selecting-manually-in-the-map-canvas (use it most days)

Answer (score 1):

If you are happy to use the centroid of the polygon you could explore using https://postcodes.io/

There are a bunch of [API's](https://postcodes.io/about) that expose this website to scripting. I'm unaware of any limits on the number of queries you can ask.